# Find an upper bound for the maximum element in a fixed-size set that is part of factoring a given integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory

To start with, my knowledge of number theory is very little and this is not a homework. The scope here is for non-prime positive integers greater than $1$. The factors of $486$ are $1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 18, 27, 54, 81, 162, 243, 486$.

$486$ can be written as a product of two numbers as follows:
$2 * 243$,
$3 * 162$,
$6 * 81$,
$9 * 54$,
$18 * 27$,
..., finally,
$243 * 2$

The maximum integer used is $243$ for a product of $2$ integers to form $486$
...

$486$ can be written as a product of $3$ numbers as:
$2 * 3 * 81$,
$3 * 3 * 81$,
...
etc.
using a set of 3 integers. The maximum integer used is $81$ for a product of $3$ integers to form $486$.

Also,$486$ can be written as a product of $4$ numbers with maximum integer of $27$.

From the above cases, I observed that we can obtain the maximum for each set of sizes 2,3,4,... by division as follows: $486/2=243$, $486/(2*3)=81$, $486/(2*3*3)=27$, $486/(2*3*3*3)=9$. However, I don't see this as a general rule.

*My question is: given a positive integer $n$ > $1$, that is non-prime, and a set of divisors of N of fixed size $S$, I want to obtain a formula that gives an upper bound for the maximum integer among the elements of $S$. I don't want to use iterations. The expected formula will be of the form $UB(N, S)=...$*

In the above case: $N=486$, when $S=2$, the maximum number is $243$. When $S=3$,the maximum number is $81.

I don't think I can determine the exact maximum number, but may be there is a 'reasonable' bound on this maximum value that can be determined without iterations.

I have spent sometime researching this using the limited material I have but found no clue or even a similar concept (there is a similar concept in integer partition though).

Comment: If I have understood the question, For a fixed $N,k$, you are looking for the least divisor of $N$ which has at least $k$ factors (not including $1$).  Thus for $(N,k)=(486,2)$, you'd want $2$ since $2$ is a divisor with $1$ factor.

Comment: You have the upper bound, $N/2^{s-1}$ (when N is divisible by $2^{s-1}$). you cannot know the exact value unless you know the prime factorization.

Comment: @lulu, thanks for you comment, I want a bound for the maximum not the least, so for 486,2 I expect 243=486/2 in this case.

Comment: wdym by a specific size?

Comment: Yes, you find my least divisor and then take the quotient.  So you can always take the lcm of the least $k$ divisors, but unless you have a prime power, this will probably not be minimal.

Comment: @DS, your suggested formula works. However, it gives numbers very far from the actual ones.

Comment: Like DS stated, knowing the actual maximum is equivalent to knowing the exact prime factorization. Namely, $UB(N, S) = S / \prod_{i=1}^S p_i$ where $p_i$ are the prime factors of $N$ arranged in non-decreasing order. The upper bound then follows by setting $p_i \geq 2$.

Comment: @CalvinLin, thanks for your comment. However, UB suggested will be less than 1. Take the case of $N=486$ with $S=3$,Here $3/486<1$.

Comment: Ah typos, should be $N / \prod_{i=1}^{S-1} p_i$. IE $UB(486, 3) = 486/ (2\times 3)$

Comment: @CalvinLin, thank you for your comment, I will test it out.